# Designing a Morse code transmit/receive shoe

Tags: transmitter, transceiver

Thank you for considering my general question, which I assure you is serious!

I want to build -- or have built -- a magnificent shoe that can convert taps (front of the shoe) into Morse code and transmits it (two taps of the heel) to a remote computer to then run a "define: " query in Google. Then, upon automatically receiving the definition translated back into Morse code, receive the code transmitted from the computer to a small vibrating unit inside the shoe, which will play out the definition in a series of Morse code vibrations. The one tap of the heel will be for 'spaces'.

What do you think? Is this achievable if I consult with a physical electrical engineer and a shoe-maker?

(the purpose is for a magic trick that I am working on)

Comment: It's very feasible. Was that all you wanted to know?

Comment: See the book "The Newtonian Casino", describing the use of a similar system to cheat at cards - over 20 years ago. Nowadays it might be possible to do it with a smartphone alone (already contains accelerometer, vibrator, radio communications, battery)

Comment: @pjc - I was just about to suggest that

Comment: Thanks guys, that's all I wanted to know - If it was achievable.

Comment: Physical EEs (as opposed to *imaginary* ones) and magic tricks.  This would actually be a *fun* project.  "SirCumference":  Heh.

Comment: You might look into wearable electronics platforms. They should be fairly easy to get started with. Examples:                                               https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/135              http://www.adafruit.com/category/92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would take a lot of engineering to make this work properly and effectively, and that won't be cheap, but the basic operation you describe should be achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Magicians sure like hiding things in shoes! About a year ago I built a signal processor for a remote control switch hidden in a shoe for a magic trick. 
What you ask for is certainly possible, but as Olin said, be prepared for a big bill.

Google "Electronics for Magicians." If you don't already have that book, it's a nice introduction to building your own circuits for magic tricks/performances. It will give you some idea of what you are up against, hopefully.